pyvis node labels don't appear sometimes
I'm using pyvis to visualize my networkx graph but sometimes when I try to load the generated HTML file, the node labels don't appear or they are quite transparent. This seems to happen randomly as the node labels appear sometimes.
I already tried disabling gravity just to check if it was just loading slowly but the labels still don't appear
